# Aplicacion de RadioButtons

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy trabajando en programa(interfaz) y tuve problemas en la aplicación de `RadioButtons`, paso a describirlo a continuación:

### Objetivo

Hacer un interfaz que al seleccionar elemento se añada a una lista predefinida de acuerdo al color seleccionado,y al cambiar de color(`RadioButton`) , la primera lista  interactúe con la lista del nuevo color , osea que al seleccionar un elemento del nuevo color , esta carta se elimine de la primer lista si esta y se añada a la nueva lista.
*esta asociado un color distinto a cada `RadioButton`*

### Importante

Que en todo momento aparezca en el `FRAME`  todos los elemento seleccionados por color y no se borre.

---

Para mas explicación vean mi programa , necesito su ayuda
cualquier duda les puedo contestar.

```
from tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()
raiz.title('program')
raiz.resizable(0, 0)
raiz.iconbitmap(r'dd.ico')
raiz.config(bg='silver', width='650', height='580')
# -------------------------------

frame1 = Frame(raiz)
frame1.place(x='8', y='0')
frame1.config(bg='silver')
Label(frame1, text=" ", font=('Helvetica', 1, 'bold'), bg='silver').grid(row='1', column='14', columnspan=1)
Label(frame1, text=" ", font=('Helvetica', 1, 'bold'), bg='silver').grid(row='15', column='1', columnspan=1)


Label(frame1, text="buttons", font=('Helvetica', 12), bg='silver').grid(row='1', column='5', columnspan=5)

#VARIABLES
#------------------------------------------------------
element1, element2, element3, element4, element5= IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar()

# ----------------------------------

off_color = "#FFE7B5"
on_color1 = '#0080BB'
on_color2 = 'red'

# ----------------------------------
def funcion_total():
    list1 = []
    list2 = []

    for i in range(5):

        # HELPME   HERE

        if opcion.get() == 1:
            if var[i].get() == 1:
                boton[i]["bg"] = on_color1
                list1+=[boton[i]['text']]
            else:
                boton[i]["bg"] = off_color
                if boton[i]['text'] in list1:
                    list1 -= [boton[i]['text']]
        else:
            ######here####
            pass

        if opcion.get() == 2:
            if var[i].get() == 1:
                boton[i]["bg"] = on_color2
                list2 += [boton[i]['text']]

            else:
                boton[i]["bg"] = off_color
                if boton[i]['text'] in list2:
                    list2 -= [boton[i]['text']]
        else:
            pass


    def gg():
        print('')
        print('    list_final=ran(', list1, ',', list2,  ')')

    buttonprint.config(command=gg)


#print
buttonprint = Button(raiz)
buttonprint.config(text='PRINT', bg='#FFCE44', relief='solid', width=35, height=5)
buttonprint.place(x='310', y='490')


#radiobuttons
opcion = IntVar()

var1= Radiobutton(frame1,text='list1',bg=on_color1, relief='solid', width=10, height=2, value=1,variable=opcion)
var1.grid(row="4", column='7', columnspan='4')
var2= Radiobutton(frame1,text='list2',bg=on_color2, relief='solid', width=10, height=2, value=2,variable=opcion)
var2.grid(row="7", column='7', columnspan='4')

#elements

text = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4', 'element5' ]
column = [1,2,3,4,5]

a1r, a2r, a3r, a4r, a5r= Checkbutton(frame1), Checkbutton(frame1), Checkbutton(frame1), Checkbutton(frame1), Checkbutton(frame1)

var = [element1, element2, element3, element4, element5]
boton = [a1r, a2r, a3r, a4r, a5r]

for i in range(5):
    boton[i].config(variable=var[i], onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=funcion_total, text=text[i], width=9, height=2, relief="raised", bg=off_color)
    boton[i].grid(row="2", column=f'{column[i]}')




raiz.mainloop()
```

[image: muestra]

Si no se puede con Tkinter pueden recomendarme con que módulo y como pero esto como último recuso, gracias

*Este no es el programa original , lo recorte y lo simplifique para mejor entendimiento del problema*

Comment: Buenas, he leído tu pregunta y no he detectado bien el problema. Hasta lo que entiendo cuando aprietas un check button, y esta seleccionada lista 1 o lista 2, este se tiene que agregar a una lista y cambiar el color instantáneamente ¿no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El principal problema si he entendido bien lo que deseas es que deberías resetear los `CheckButtons` adecuadamente cuando se cambia de una lista a otra (se selecciona un `RadioButton`). Para ello solo necesitarías usar el método `trace_all` de la variable `opcion`.

```
import tkinter as tk


# CONSTANTES
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
OFF_COLOR = "#FFE7B5"
ON_COLOR1 = '#0080BB'
ON_COLOR2 = 'red'

# FUNCIONES
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


def imprimir_listas():
    colors = {ON_COLOR1: [], ON_COLOR2: [], OFF_COLOR: []}
    for btn, _ in check_buttons:
        colors[btn["bg"]].append(btn["text"])
    print(f'\n    list_final=ran({colors[ON_COLOR1]}, {colors[ON_COLOR2]})')


def cambiar_lista(botones, color):
    for btn, var in check_buttons:
        if btn["bg"] == color:
            var.set(1)
        else:
            var.set(0)


def seleccionar(button, check_buttons):
    for btn, var in check_buttons:
        if btn is button:
            if var.get():
                btn.config(bg=opcion.get())
            else:
                btn.config(bg=OFF_COLOR)


# INTERFAZ
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Ventana principal
raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title('Program')
raiz.resizable(0, 0)
# raiz.iconbitmap(r'dd.ico')
raiz.config(bg='silver', width='650', height='580')

# Frame
frame1 = tk.Frame(raiz)
frame1.place(x='8', y='0')
frame1.config(bg='silver')

# Etiquetas
tk.Label(
    frame1, text=" ", font=('Helvetica', 1, 'bold'), bg='silver'
    ).grid(row='1', column='14', columnspan=1)

tk.Label(
    frame1, text=" ", font=('Helvetica', 1, 'bold'), bg='silver'
    ).grid(row='15', column='1', columnspan=1)

tk.Label(
    frame1, text="buttons", font=('Helvetica', 12), bg='silver'
    ).grid(row='1', column='5', columnspan=5)

# Botón para mostrar
tk.Button(
    raiz, text='PRINT', bg='#FFCE44', relief='solid',
    command=imprimir_listas, width=35, height=5
    ).place(x='310', y='490')

# Radiobuttons
opcion = tk.StringVar(raiz, ON_COLOR1)
tk.Radiobutton(
    frame1, text='list1', bg=ON_COLOR1, relief='solid',
    width=10, height=2, value=ON_COLOR1, variable=opcion
    ).grid(row="4", column='7', columnspan='4')

tk.Radiobutton(
    frame1, text='list2', bg=ON_COLOR2, relief='solid',
    width=10, height=2, value=ON_COLOR2, variable=opcion
    ).grid(row="7", column='7', columnspan='4')
opcion.trace_add("write", lambda *_: cambiar_lista(check_buttons, opcion.get()))

# Elements
texts = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4', 'element5']

check_buttons = []
for i, text in enumerate(texts):
    var = tk.IntVar(raiz)
    btn = tk.Checkbutton(
        frame1, variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
        text=text, width=9, height=2, relief="raised", bg=OFF_COLOR
        )
    btn.config(command=lambda btn=btn: seleccionar(btn, check_buttons))
    btn.grid(row="2", column=i + 1)
    check_buttons.append([btn, var])

raiz.mainloop()
```

He reestructurado algo el código para simplificar algunas cosas, además he eliminado el wildcard (`from tkinter import *`), es una mala práctica. El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Maraviloso internet!!!, es lo que buscaba ,muchisimas gracias amigo FJSevilla

Comment: puedes explicarme un poco el codigo, amigo cual es el uso del guion bajo en la definicion de imprimir_listas()

Comment: El `_` bajo en `for btn, _ in check_buttons` es solo una convención, cuando necesitamos asignar algo a una variable pero **no vamos a usar dicha variable nunca** se usa como nombre un guión bajo. Es lo mismo que `for btn, var in check_buttons:`, solo que en este caso si usamos el segundo item de cada sublista (la variable) por lo que le damos como nombre `var`, pero es solo eso, una convención. Se aplica también a funciones, si una necesita aceptar un argumento pero no lo va a usar se hace: `def foo(_):` no `def foo(arg_que_no_voy_a_usar):`