# ¿Que significado tienen los argumentos de lambda aquí?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, programación-funcional

¿Qué significa la siguiente expresión?:

```
lambda *_:
```

forma parte del siguiente código:

```
opcion.trace_add("write", lambda *_: cambiar_lista(check_buttons, opcion.get()))
```

¿y aquí?:

```
command=lambda btn=btn: seleccionar(btn, check_buttons)
```

Si quieren ver el código completo esta aquí, [en la respuesta a esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/345348/aplicacion-de-radiobuttons/345426?noredirect=1#comment624875_345426).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el primer caso

- `*` en éste contexto permite aceptar un numero indeterminado de argumentos posicionales, cero, uno o los que sean. Esos argumentos son empaquetados en una tupla:

  ```
  >>> def foo(*args):
          print(args)

  >>> foo("hola", 3, 4.25)
  ('hola', 3, 4.25)

  >>> foo()
  ()
  >>> foo(45)
  (45)
  ```
- `_` en este caso es solo una convención (en vez de usar `args`) que indica que no vamos a usar esos argumentos en la función, la función los acepta porque debe aceptarlos por alguna razón (quien la llama pasa argumentos) pero luego no hace uso de ellos

  Por lo tanto, `*_` indica que la función lambda aceptara cualquier número de argumentos posicionales pero no va a usarlos para nada.

La función `lambda` no tiene nada de especial con esta sintaxis, es equivalente a:

```
def on_opcion(*_):
    cambiar_lista(check_buttons, opcion.get())

opcion.trace_add("write", on_opcion)
```

cuando el evento tiene lugar (la `StringVar` se modifica) se pasan una serie de argumentos a la función que son el primero el nombre interno de la variable, el segundo el índice si es una variable tipo lista o una cadena vacía si no y el tercero es el tipo de operación que causé el evento (write, read, etc). Como estos argumento se pasan, la callback tiene que aceptarlos o tendríamos una excepción, pero como no se hace uso de ellos se usa la comentada sintaxis. También se podría hacer:

```
lambda _, _, _: cambiar_lista(check_buttons, opcion.get())
```

realmente:

```
lambda nombre, idx, oper: cambiar_lista(check_buttons, opcion.get())
```

sería perfectamente válido en cuanto a sintaxis, lo de usar `_` no deja de ser una convención.

---

En cuanto al segundo, es un argumento por defecto, similar a:

> ```
> >>> def foo(argumento="Hola"):
>         print(argumento)
>
> >>> foo()
> Hola
>
> >>> foo("Adiós")
> Adios
> ```

La razón de usarlo es que el cuerpo de las expresiones `lambda` al igual que el de las funciones normales **se evalúa cuando son ejecutadas**. Si hacemos:

```
command=lambda: seleccionar(btn, check_buttons)
```

la expresión `seleccionar(btn, check_buttons)` se evalúa cuando el botón es pulsado, el problema es que `btn` se define en un `for`, por lo que en cada iteración cambia apuntando a un nuevo botón. Esto provocaría que cuando se evalúa la expresión `btn` sería el último botón creado en todas las lambda, eso si no hemos reasignado algo a la variable o si ésta no era local a una función que generó los botones, en cuyo caso ni existirá.

Podemos comprobarlo de forma muy simple, si hacemos:

```
>>> def foo():
        int("hola")
```

no pasa nada, no hay excepción. Esto pasa porque el intérprete crea el objeto para representar la función en memoria, pero no ejecuta nada de lo que contiene. Ahora, si ejecutamos `int("hola")` si se ejecuta y:

> ```
> >>> foo()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "main", line 1, in <module>
>     foo()
>
>   File "main", line 2, in foo
>     int("hola")
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hola'
> ```

Si cometemos la misma estupidez al crear una función con un atributo con valor por defecto:

> ```
> >>> def foo(arg=int("hola")):
>         pass
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "main", line 1, in <module>
>     def foo(arg=int("hola")):
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hola'
> ```

El intérprete necesita conocer el nombre de los argumentos y su valor por defecto para construir el objeto, por lo que evalúa el código del argumento por defecto **cuando definimos la función** y no cuando se ejecuta como ocurría antes.

Un ejemplo muy simple usando Tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

for i in range(5):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=str(i), command=lambda: print(btn["text"]))
    btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

todos imprimen "4", porque `btn` cuando la expresión lambda se ejecuta es la referencia al último botón creado en todas las callbacks. Una forma de evitar esto es pasar el botón como argumento por defecto a la función `lambda`. Como **los argumentos, al contrario que el cuerpo, son evaluados en tiempo de definición, no en tiempo de ejecución.**, esto hace que cuando se evalúa el cuerpo se tome el argumento `btn` por defecto que ahora si hace referencia a cada botón.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

for i in range(5):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=str(i))
    btn.config(command=lambda btn=btn: print(btn["text"]))
    btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Otra forma de evitar esto es usar `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

for i in range(5):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=str(i))
    btn.config(command=partial(print, btn["text"]))
    btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola Norvin no te preocupes por "molestar", para eso estamos todos aquí para aprender todos los días algo, respondiendo o preguntando. En cuanto a tus dudas, para guardar bastaría con que en la función en la que imprimes abras un archivo with open("salida.txt", "w") as f: f.write("lo que quieras escribir"). Dependerá del formato que quieras que tenga el archivo. En cuanto a los segundo, ¿la idea sería substituir los check_buttons por el árbol o cada check_buttons se correspondería con una columna por ejemplo?

Comment: Es complicado por comentarios y da para una nueva pregunta o dos realmente y aque son dos problemas. Intenta si no algo primero para que la pregunta sea aceptable para el sitio  y crea una nueva pregunta explicando detalladamente el resultado que esperas conseguir (formato del archivo, contenido del tree y que se debe editar en él, etc). Será mucho más fácil para ti explicarlo y responder adecuadamente.

Comment: Excelente, iré haciendo el código entonces,ojala que los dioses de python me sean propicios :)