# ¿Cómo acceder a los metodos "width" y "height" de un "Label" -"tkinter" en una ventana "Toplevel" a través de una función?

Tags: python, tkinter, scale

El siguiente código Python y libreria Tkinter, crea una ventana principal con un único botón, que al pulsarlo crea una ventana hija con “TopLevel” esta ventana tiene dos widgets de barra de desplazamiento “Scale” (uno horizontal y otro vertical) que al deslizarlos hacen que un “Label” en el centro de la pantalla aumente o disminuya su tamaño. El problema es que cuando el “command” de los “Scale’s” llama a las funciones “modificar_ancho(valor)” y “modificar_alto(valor)“ la etiqueta “eti_cuadrado” (Que es la que tiene que modificar su tamaño) no es visible dentro de estas funciones.

Código:

```
    import tkinter as tk


    def modificar_ancho(valor):
        texte = str(valor) + "X" + str(al.get())
        presenta.set(texte)
        eti_cuadrado.config(width=2*an.get())
        # Error considera eti_cuadrado como no definido


    def modificar_alto(valor):
        texte = str(an.get()) + "X" + str(valor)
        presenta.set(texte)
        eti_cuadrado.config(height=al.get())
        # Error considera eti_cuadrado como no definido


    def abrir_ventana2():
        ventana2 = tk.Toplevel(ventana)  # crea una segunda ventana
        ventana2.title("Cuadrado a escala")
        ventana2.geometry("400x320")
        al.set(1)  # Inicializa el Scale vertical.
        an.set(1)  # Inicializa el Scale horizontal.
        presenta.set("")

        alto = tk.Scale(ventana2, from_=1, to=10, length=200,
                        label="Altura", variable=al, tickinterval="1",
                        command=modificar_alto)
        alto.place(x=0, y=10)

        ancho = tk.Scale(ventana2, from_=1, to=15, length=300,
                         label="Anchura", variable=an, tickinterval="1",
                         orient="horizontal",
                         command=modificar_ancho)
        ancho.place(x=40, y=230)

        eti_cuadrado = tk.Label(ventana2, bg="lightgreen", textvar=presenta, bd=10,
                                relief="raised")
        eti_cuadrado.place(x=90, y=50)


    ventana = tk.Tk()

    presenta = tk.StringVar()
    al = tk.IntVar()
    an = tk.IntVar()
    ventana.title("Cuadrado")
    ventana.geometry("380x320")
    ventana.resizable(False, False)
    boton = tk.Button(ventana, text="Abir ventana", command=abrir_ventana2)
    boton.pack()

    ventana.mainloop()
```

Preguntas:

¿Cómo puedo hacer visible la etiqueta "eti_cuadrado" dentro de las funciones: modificar_ancho(valor) y modificar_alto(valor)?.

¿Hay alguna manera de declarar "eti_cuadrado" como global?.

¿Se puede pasar una instancia del label como parametro a una función?, ¿como?.

¿Conoceis otra manera de implementar el código para realizar lo que quiero hacer?

He probado las siguientes acciones y no funcionan:

- Declarar la función anteponiendo el nombre de las ventanas con un punto:

  ```
  def modificar_alto(valor):

      texte = str(an.get()) + "X" + str(valor)

      presenta.set(texte)

      ventana.ventana2.eti_cuadrado.config(height=al.get())
  ```
- Poner el height y el width en la declaracion del "Label" asignando las varibles de los valores de "Scale":

  ```
  eti_cuadrado = tk.Label(ventana2, bg="lightgreen", textvar=presenta, bd=10,
                          width=2*an.get(), height=al.get(), relief="raised")
  ```
- Enviar como parametro la etiqueta "eti_cuadrado" a las funciones modificar_alto y modificar_ancho:

  ```
  command=modificar_alto(eti_cuadrado)

  command=modificar_ancho(eti_cuadrado)
  ```

Todas estas acciones no han funcionado, la única forma en que he conseguido que las barras deslizantes "Scale" y la etiqueta "eti_cuadrado" funcione como quiero ha sido olvidándome de la ventana hija y poniendo todo el código en la ventana principal, así:

```
    import tkinter as tk


    def modificar_ancho(valor):
        texte = str(valor) + "X" + str(al.get())
        presenta.set(texte)
        eti_cuadrado.config(width=2*an.get())


    def modificar_alto(valor):
        texte = str(an.get()) + "X" + str(valor)
        presenta.set(texte)
        eti_cuadrado.config(height=al.get())


    ventana = tk.Tk()
    presenta = tk.StringVar()
    al = tk.IntVar()
    an = tk.IntVar()
    ventana.title("Cuadrado a escala")
    ventana.geometry("380x320")
    al.set(1)
    an.set(1)
    presenta.set("")

    alto = tk.Scale(ventana, from_=1, to=10, length=200,
                    label="Altura", variable=al, tickinterval="1",
                    command=modificar_alto)
    alto.place(x=0, y=10)

    ancho = tk.Scale(ventana, from_=1, to=15, length=300,
                     label="Anchura", variable=an, tickinterval="1",
                     orient="horizontal",
                     command=modificar_ancho)
    ancho.place(x=40, y=230)

    eti_cuadrado = tk.Label(ventana, bg="lightgreen", textvar=presenta, bd=10,
                            relief="raised")
    eti_cuadrado.place(x=90, y=50)
    ventana.mainloop()
```

Pero para realizar el programa que estoy implementando necesitaría poder ampliar y reducir el tamaño del "Label" eti_cuadrado en la ventana hija o secundaria (Toplevel), ya que dicho programa va creando varias ventanas hijas, una por cada terea que realiza el programa. Agradezco de antemano toda la ayuda que me podáis dar.

¿Podeis ayudarme?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente `eti_cuadrado` es una variable definida dentro de la función y por tanto es local por defecto, en cuanto la función retorna deja de existir y por tanto es inaccesible desde fuera de la misma.

Tienes muchas opciones:

### Hacer que sea global

```
def modificar_ancho(valor):
    texte = str(valor) + "X" + str(al.get())
    presenta.set(texte)
    eti_cuadrado.config(width=2*an.get())


def modificar_alto(valor):
    texte = str(an.get()) + "X" + str(valor)
    presenta.set(texte)
    eti_cuadrado.config(height=al.get())


def abrir_ventana2():
    global eti_cuadrado
    ventana2 = tk.Toplevel(ventana)  # crea una segunda ventana
    ventana2.title("Cuadrado a escala")
    ventana2.geometry("400x320")
    al.set(1)  # Inicializa el Scale vertical.
    an.set(1)  # Inicializa el Scale horizontal.
    presenta.set("")

    alto = tk.Scale(ventana2, from_=1, to=10, length=200,
                    label="Altura", variable=al, tickinterval="1",
                    command=modificar_alto)
    alto.place(x=0, y=10)

    ancho = tk.Scale(ventana2, from_=1, to=15, length=300,
                     label="Anchura", variable=an, tickinterval="1",
                     orient="horizontal",
                     command=modificar_ancho)
    ancho.place(x=40, y=230)

    eti_cuadrado = tk.Label(ventana2, bg="lightgreen", textvar=presenta, bd=10,
                            relief="raised")
    eti_cuadrado.place(x=90, y=50)
```

Las variables globales deben evitarse en lo posible, lo mejor es usarlas solo para constantes. Es más **no funcionará si quieres crear varias ventanas secundarias simultáneamente ya que sobrescribes la variable `eti_cuadrado` en cada llamada a la función.**

### Pasar el label como argumento

Esto lo puedes conseguir con funciones lambda o una normal que actúe como wrapper:

```
def modificar_ancho(valor, label):

    texte = str(valor) + "X" + str(al.get())
    presenta.set(texte)
    label.config(width=2*an.get())

def modificar_alto(valor, label):
    texte = str(an.get()) + "X" + str(valor)
    presenta.set(texte)
    label.config(height=al.get())


def abrir_ventana2():
    ventana2 = tk.Toplevel(ventana)  # crea una segunda ventana
    ventana2.title("Cuadrado a escala")
    ventana2.geometry("400x320")
    al.set(1)  # Inicializa el Scale vertical.
    an.set(1)  # Inicializa el Scale horizontal.
    presenta.set("")

    eti_cuadrado = tk.Label(ventana2, bg="lightgreen", textvar=presenta, bd=10,
                            relief="raised")
    eti_cuadrado.place(x=90, y=50)

    alto = tk.Scale(
        ventana2, from_=1, to=10, length=200, label="Altura",
        variable=al, tickinterval="1",
        command=lambda val, label=eti_cuadrado: (modificar_alto(val, label))
        )
    alto.place(x=0, y=10)

    ancho = tk.Scale(
        ventana2, from_=1, to=15, length=300, label="Anchura", variable=an,
        tickinterval="1", orient="horizontal",
        command=lambda val, label=eti_cuadrado: (modificar_ancho(val, label))
        )
    ancho.place(x=40, y=230)
```

Para una explicación más detallada puedes mirarte la siguiente pregunta:

- [que significado tienen los argumentos de LAMBDA aqui?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/346778/15089)

### Declarar las funciones dentro de `abrir_ventana2`

```
def abrir_ventana2():
    def modificar_ancho(valor):
        texte = str(valor) + "X" + str(al.get())
        presenta.set(texte)
        eti_cuadrado.config(width=2*an.get())

    def modificar_alto(valor):
        texte = str(an.get()) + "X" + str(valor)
        presenta.set(texte)
        eti_cuadrado.config(height=al.get())

    ventana2 = tk.Toplevel(ventana)  # crea una segunda ventana
    ventana2.title("Cuadrado a escala")
    ventana2.geometry("400x320")
    al.set(1)  # Inicializa el Scale vertical.
    an.set(1)  # Inicializa el Scale horizontal.
    presenta.set("")

    alto = tk.Scale(ventana2, from_=1, to=10, length=200,
                    label="Altura", variable=al, tickinterval="1",
                    command=modificar_alto)
    alto.place(x=0, y=10)

    ancho = tk.Scale(ventana2, from_=1, to=15, length=300,
                     label="Anchura", variable=an, tickinterval="1",
                     orient="horizontal",
                     command=modificar_ancho)
    ancho.place(x=40, y=230)

    eti_cuadrado = tk.Label(ventana2, bg="lightgreen", textvar=presenta, bd=10,
                            relief="raised")
    eti_cuadrado.place(x=90, y=50)
```

### Usa POO y representar cada ventana con una clase

Creo que es la opción más elegante y más escalable sin duda:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        tk.Button(
            self, text="Abir ventana", command=self.abrir_ventana_secundaria
            ).pack()

    def abrir_ventana_secundaria(self):
        VentanaSecundaria(self)


class VentanaSecundaria(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title("Cuadrado a escala")
        self.geometry("400x320")
        self.al = tk.IntVar(self, 1)
        self.an = tk.IntVar(self, 1)
        self.presenta = tk.StringVar(self, "")

        tk.Scale(self, from_=1, to=10, length=200,
                 label="Altura", variable=self.al, tickinterval="1",
                 command=self.modificar_alto).place(x=0, y=10)

        tk.Scale(self, from_=1, to=15, length=300,
                 label="Anchura", variable=self.an, tickinterval="1",
                 orient="horizontal",
                 command=self.modificar_ancho).place(x=40, y=230)

        self.eti_cuadrado = tk.Label(
            self, bg="lightgreen", textvar=self.presenta,
            bd=10, relief="raised"
            )
        self.eti_cuadrado.place(x=90, y=50)

    def modificar_ancho(self, valor):
        texte = f"{valor}X{self.al.get()}"
        self.presenta.set(texte)
        self.eti_cuadrado.config(width=2 * self.an.get())

    def modificar_alto(self, valor):
        texte = f"{self.an.get()}X{valor}"
        self.presenta.set(texte)
        self.eti_cuadrado.config(height=self.al.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ventana = tk.Tk()
    ventana.title("Cuadrado")
    ventana.geometry("380x320")
    ventana.resizable(False, False)
    MainWindow(ventana).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    ventana.mainloop()
```

---

Ahora voy a intentar explicar porqué no funciona cada uno de tus intentos:

- > Declarar la función anteponiendo el nombre de las ventanas con un
  >   punto:

  Si haces esto:

  ```
  ventana.ventana2.eti_cuadrado.config(height=al.get())
  ```

  la altura es estática, cuando se llama a `config` se obtiene en ese momento el valor de la variable y se le asigna a `heigh`. Si luego cambia nada se modifica.
- > Poner el height y el width en la declaracion del "Label" asignando las
  >   varibles de los valores de "Scale":

  ```
  eti_cuadrado = tk.Label(ventana2, bg="lightgreen", textvar=presenta, bd=10,
                  width=2*an.get(), height=al.get(), relief="raised")
  ```

  el problema es el mismo que antes, cuando se instancia el widget se obtiene el valor de las variables (que será 0) y se le asigna a width y height. Cuando se modifiquen las variables no cambiará nada.
- > Enviar como parametro la etiqueta "eti_cuadrado" a las funciones modificar_alto y modificar_ancho:

  ```
  command=modificar_alto(eti_cuadrado)
  ```

  en este caso tu solución sería similar a mi segunda solución. No funciona porque lo que **le pasas a `command` es el retorno de la función** (**None** en este caso) cuando debes pasarle la referencia a la misma para que pueda llamarse cuanod el evento tenga lugar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu colaboración me has ayudado muchisimo y ahora con tu extensa explicación entiendo muchas cosas que no entendia. No sabes la de horas que he pasado en Google buscando una respuesta.